# monitor imagemagick convert progress with python

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Using ImageMagick I can convert some really large images via

```
convert -monitor GIANT_FILE.jpg GIANT_DIFF_FORMAT.png
```

Which gives this feedback on the command line:

```
load image[GIANT_FILE.jpg]: 14999 of 15000, 100% complete
load image[GIANT_DIFF_FORMAT.png]: 14999 of 15000, 100% complete
```

(where the percent complete updates on each line).
How would I monitor the updates to the percentages from the command line in realtime with python?  And how would I know when the command is done?

I currently use

```
cmd = "convert -monitor GIANT_FILE.jpg GIANT_DIFF_FORMAT.png" 
output, error = subprocess.Popen( cmd.split(), stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()
```

But this does not let me monitor the progress... at lease not that I am aware of.

Comment: imagemagick actually has a "progress monitor."  I've never used it, but it might be possible to use it either from the standard bindings or from wand.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin That's right. Your thinking of [MagickSetProgressMonitor](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-property.php#MagickSetProgressMonitor)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to work directly with ImageMagick's C-API to build out a progress monitor. [Wand](http://wand-py.org) is a great library, but there are others.

The goal is to connect [MagickSetProgressMonitor](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-property.php#MagickSetProgressMonitor) with your python code. Here's an example with [wand](/questions/tagged/wand)

```py
import ctypes
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

# Create a python callback function
def my_monitor(text, offset, span, client_data=None):
    message = ctypes.cast(text, ctypes.c_char_p).value
    if span:
        print("{0}: {1:0.2f}".format(message.decode(), offset / span))
    return 1 # Return 1 to continue, 0 to halt

# Register C function signature
CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p,   # text
                           ctypes.c_longlong, # offset
                           ctypes.c_size_t,   # span
                           ctypes.c_void_p)   # user_data

# Prototype MagickSetProgressMonitor on Wand's library instance
library.MagickSetProgressMonitor.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,  # wand
                                             CMPFUNC,          # function
                                             ctypes.c_void_p)  # user_data

# Map Python function to C function, and hold in global instance
callback = CMPFUNC(my_monitor)

# Subclass wand.image.Image class and attached progress monitor
class MyImage(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # init parent to allocate wand resource
        super(MyImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.user_data = None # Hold a NULL pointer on instance
        library.MagickSetProgressMonitor(self.wand,
                                         callback,
                                         self.user_data)
```

Example output

```
>>> with MyImage() as img:
...    img.read(filename='wizard:')
...    img.resize(10, 10)

Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.00
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.05
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.10
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.15
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.20
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.25
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.30
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.35
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.40
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.45
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.50
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.55
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.60
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.65
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.70
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.75
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.80
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.85
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.90
Resize/Image/WIZARD: 0.95
```